# Create a typed dataset from code

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

for the purpose of a test, I would like to mock my typed dataset. So I want to create it, with appropriate value, with C# code.
But I don't know how to do that. Each tutorial I see, are about non-typed dataset.

Has someone an example ? Or maybe a link that explain this ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You want to put data in the dataset without using the database?  Do you want the input data in XML format or just in code?

Answer (score 2):

`System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator` in `System.Design.dll`

Comment: All the classes are already generated, what I want is to fill them without using the database